# LINQ performance group by object vs group by id

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a group by statement like so:

```
group s by c into g
select new ObjectDto
{
  KeyObject = new KeyObjectDto
  {
      ObjectId = g.Key.Id
  },
  GroupedObjects = g.Select(a => a)
};
```

If I modify this `ObjectDto` to have an `IEnumerable` `KeyObjects` and modify the query like below I am seeing 2x the performance improvement:

```
group s by c.Id into g
select new ObjectDto
{
  KeyObjects = KeyObjectsDbSet.Where(x => x.Id == g.Key).Select(x => new KeyObjectDto
  {
      ObjectId = x.Id
  }),
  GroupedObjects = g.Select(a => a)
};
```

If I look at the generated SQL from the first statement it looks like grouping by `c` uses more than just the `Id` to compare if two rows are unique or not (despite the fact that EF is aware of the `Id` being the primary key), but I wasn't sure that's all that's at play here. I also noticed that if instead try:

```
KeyObject = KeyObjectsDbSet.Where(x => x.Id == g.Key).Select(x => new KeyObjectDto
      {
          ObjectId = x.Id
      }).FirstOrDefault()
```

that I immediately lose any performance benefits.

So my questions are:

(1) Why is the performance of the second better than the first statement (is it just because of the row/object comparison)?

(2) Is it possible to group by object, but tell LINQ to use a specific property (set of properties) on which to do that grouping? For instance: `group s by c using c.Id into g`

Comment: The first query fetches full `c` entities, vs only `c.Id` in the second query. I can't explain your third observation though. I guess it's all related to query shapes that can be optimized better/worse.

Comment: For (2), that is what `group s by c.Id into g` means.

Comment: Yes thanks I have since realized that :)